# Advise on Custom Segue XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, segue

I'm interested in replicating the transition features in the picture below.

I have noticed this being used in multiple apps but am not sure where to start.

The transition literally pushes the current screen away in a direction and is followed by the requested screen. In the picture below, the paper plan button is pressed to initiate this transition

Does anyone know how to create this custom segue or does anyone know of any projects on Github that demonstrate this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its not a segue you would use. you would use the childViewControllers property of UIViewController to add left and right view controllers than do some animation tricks and gesture recognizers to get it how you want it to look. There are tons of tutorials online just look them up if you don't want to come up with one from scratch.